# How to take m smallest elements from n sorted *named* vectors with time complexity n+mlgn

Tags: c++

Consider the following code where we take out the smallest number [fullcode](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LgZj3RESMTiCBU31)

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v1{158,200}, v2{143,158};
    using pii = pair<vector<int>&,int>;  // notice the & here.
    auto comp = [](const auto &a, const auto &b) {
        const auto &av = a.first, &bv = b.first;
        int aidx = a.second, bidx = b.second;
        return av[aidx] > bv[bidx];
    };
    priority_queue<pii, vector<pii>, decltype(comp)> pq(comp);
    pq.push({v1, 0});
    pq.push({v2, 0});
    
    // outputs 158 not 143
    cout << pq.top().first[pq.top().second] << endl;
    
    // v2 got overwritten as v1
    cout << v2[0] << endl;
}
```

The answer is 158 not 143 because the element of pair is a reference and hence v2 got overwritten as v1 in operations within pq.push.

Omitting the reference and full copy the vector is not feasible as the vectors are very large in real application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pointers. Since the pointer is not owning so the usage is ok.

```
using pii = pair<vector<int>*, int>;
```